# Finding a specific value of input when having multiple forms on a page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been trying to find a way for my jQuery AJAX-script to find out the values of my posted form, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've probably missed out on some fundamental knowledge.

Anyhow. This is my jQuery so far:

```
function updaterow(sub){

            var form = sub.form;

            var ID = $(form).find('input[name="ID"]').val();

            var ArtName = $(form).find('input[name="ArtName"]').val();

            var ArtNumber = $(form).find('input[name="ArtNumber"]').val();

            var CustContact = $(form).find('input[name="CustContact"]').val();

            var SupStatus = $(form).find('select[name="SupStatus"]').val();

            var SupName = $(form).find('select[name="SupName"]').val();

            var OrderOther = $(form).find('textarea[name="OrderOther"]').val();



            var dataString = 'ID=' + ID + '&ArtName=' + ArtName + '&ArtNumber=' + ArtNumber + '&CustContact=' + CustContact + '&SupStatus=' + SupStatus + '&SupName=' + SupName + '&OrderOther=' + OrderOther;

            alert(sub.form);
            alert(dataString);

            return false;
        }
```

EDIT: This returns every variable as undefined in Firefox. It seems to be correct in IE 9.

This is my HTML(PHP), this is also updated to contain a few more input fields:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo "<tr><form id='".$row['ID']."' class='fcform'>
                    <td class='idcell'><input type='text' class='fcid' name='ID' readonly='readonly' value='".$row['ID']."' /></td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='ArtName' value=' ".$row['ArtName']."' /></td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='ArtNumber' value='".$row['ArtNumber']."' /></td>
                    <td><a href='/singlepost.php?ID=".$row['ID']."' title='Skriv ut ".$row['CustName']."'>".$row['CustName']."</a></td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='CustContact' value='".$row['CustContact']."' /></td>
                    <td>
                        <select name='SupStatus' class='fcsupstatus'>
                            <option value='".$row['SupStatus']."'>".$row['SupRealStatus']."</option>
                            <option value='01'>Mottagen</option>
                            <option value='02'>Lagd i korg</option>
                            <option value='03'>Beställd</option>
                            <option value='04'>Ankommen</option>
                            <option value='05'>Slutförd</option>
                            <option value='06'>Nekad</option>
                        </select>
                    <td>
                        <select>
                            <option value='".$row['SupName']."'>".$row['SupRealName']."</option>
                            <option value='01'>2020</option>
                            <option value='02'>Order</option>
                            <option value='03'>Brightpoint</option>
                            <option>---------</option>
                            <option value='04'>12 Volt</option>
                            <option value='05'>Armour</option>
                            <option value='06'>Brodit</option>
                            <option value='07'>Captech</option>
                            <option value='08'>DLS</option>
                            <option value='09'>Garmin</option>
                            <option value='10'>GL Batterier</option>
                            <option value='11'>Ingram</option>
                            <option value='12'>Isicom</option>
                            <option value='13'>KGK</option>
                            <option value='14'>MTU</option>
                            <option value='15'>Peltor</option>
                            <option value='16'>Pioneer</option>
                            <option value='17'>TMT</option>
                            <option value='18'>Övriga</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>".$row['Date']."</td>
                    <td>
                        <textarea name='OrderOther' cols='40' rows='3' class='fcorderother'>".$row['OrderOther']."</textarea>
                        <input class='savebutton' type='button' value=' ' name='Submit".$row['ID']."' onClick='updaterow(this);' />
                    </td>
                    </form></tr>";}
```

I have posted this as another post but then I was asking why my ajax wasn't posted. That's fixed now, but now the problem with the variables has arisen. Just can't see why...

I can't use ID since the forms are generated dynamically. But it doesn't seem that the jQuery knows which form I want to post.

I've tried using traversal with classes as well as by name, but to no avail.

EDIT:
Link to the files:

http://bilradiocentrum.se/txt/listheader.txt

http://bilradiocentrum.se/txt/orderlist.txt

http://bilradiocentrum.se/txt/updaterowajax.txt

Comment: What about `$('input[name=ID]').val()`

Comment: how `updaterow` is attached to the form element? by any html attribute or by jquery?

Comment: `var form = this;`? by your code it seems that `this` refer nothing , no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **add a parameter to `updateRow`** function (line #1). And **get the form object from the parameter** (line #2).

See how is done bellow.

```
function updaterow(sub){ // (line #1)
    var form= sub.form;  // (line #2)
    var ID = $(form.ID]).val();
    var SupStatus = $(form.SupStatus).val();
 ...
```

Here `form` will be your form as you have used `onClick='updaterow(this);'` in an `input` element  `sub` will be the input element. And `sub.form` will be the form containing the input element. Hence form get the actual form.

#### Update

There is problem in jquery find statement. use `$(form.NAME).val()` where NAME is the element name such as *ArtName*, *ID*, *OrderOther* etc. ( I have updated the code above too).

**Another option** is to use a unique key as Id for each element. See bellow the example,

```
<input id='ArtName-".$row['ID']"' type='text' name='ArtName' value=' ".$row['ArtName']."' />
```

Now can fetch this row in `updaterow()` function easily by `$("#ArtName-"+$(form).prop('id'))` or by `$("ArtName-"+ID)`.

The later will work only if you change the update function to `updaterow(sub, ID)` and change the *submit* input element to

```
<input class='savebutton' type='button' value=' ' name='Submit".$row['ID']."' onClick='updaterow(this, \"".$row['ID']."\");' />
```

Comment: @JohannesOhlsson I have updated the answer completely. See it. I hope there will be no problem now.

Answer (score 1):

A simple change will fix your problem:

Change:

```
               <input type='button' value='Spara' name='Submit".$row['ID']."' onClick='updaterow(this);' />
```

To:

```
               <input type='button' value='Spara' name='Submit".$row['ID']."' onClick=updaterow('".$row['ID']."'); />
```

And in your script:

```
function updaterow(formid){

            var form = document.getElementById(formid); //Why you need this line??

            var ID = $("#"+formid).find('input[name="ID"]').val();

            var SupStatus = $("#"+formid).find('input[name="SupStatus"]').val();
            var OrderOther = $("#"+formid).find('input[name="OrderOther"]').val();
```

**EDIT:** I added quotes to the values of the name attribute. (update your js code and try now)

Comment: This returns undefined as well.

Comment: 2 things: 1.When you'r `viewing source` , what's written in the line of the button (is there a number instead the variable `onClick=updaterow('".$row['ID']."'); />`) ? 2.Try adding `alert(formid)` at the `updaterow` function.

Comment: 1. Yes, there's a number:
<input type='button' value='Spara' name='Submit39' onClick=updaterow('39'); />
2. Yes, it returns an ID as numbers (in the case I just tried it was 39).

Comment: wait a second , what was returned undefiend exatcly?

Comment: the values that's represented by ID, SupStatus and OrderOther. Basically the things that I want to send on with the post :D so say: var ID = $("#"+formid).find('input[name=ID]').val(); returns undefined.

Comment: I've also tried alert(ID); just below where the variable is "defined" and it returns undefined.

Comment: There is problem with the `find` function , I edited my answer by adding quotes in the to the it. I guess that without the quotes the script thinks that `ID` is a variable.

Comment: Hmmm, tried this now. But it doesn't seem to work either. I will try navigating with children, but I won't get my hopes up yet ;)

Comment: Yeah, tried using var SupStatus = $("#"+formid).children('td.idcell').children('input[name="SupStatus"]').val(); but it didn't work either... going to upload all of the used files as .txt and I will link to them in the original post.